# How to initialize a field that accepts an IEnumerable

Tags: c#-4.0, ienumerable

I have a property `public IEnumerable<T> PieceMovement { get; set; }`

what object should I use to initialize this property. I'm thinking that the simpliest .net implementation of IEnumerable will do but what would that object be and is this the right idea?

Comment: It depends.  What do you want it to have?

Comment: What SLaks said. Also, you may want to consider making the property setter private, to prevent other code from replacing your entire sequence with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `List<T>` or a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

If you're initializing it based on an existing sequence, you could set it to a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not strictly related to IEnumerable but to good OOP design practices in general.

Since you are exposing PieceMovement as an IEnumerable every object which implements IEnumerable is a good candidate.

You should never make assoumptions of the actual type so your idea is good to me. I also usually use List